# Why does adding/removing curly braces in this arrow function cause the text to not display for a ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

```
    const tasks = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Doctors Appointment',
        day: "Feb 5th at 2:30 pm",
        reminder: true,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Meeting at School",
        day: "Feb 6th at 1:30pm",
        reminder: true,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Food Shopping",
        day: "Feb 5th at 2:30pm",
        reminder: false,
    },
];

    const Tasks = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {
                
                    tasks.map((task) =>
                        <h3>{task.text}</h3>
                )
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Tasks;
```

This is my component.
Initially I had curly braces in the arrow function, so it looked like this:

```
tasks.map((task) => {
                        <h3>{task.text}</h3>
                    }
```

However, doing so made the text disappear. So I removed these curly braces and suddenly the text appeared.

Why does adding curly braces break this arrow function?

Thanks!

Comment: In the`map` function, data needs to be returned. You write an arrow function without brackets, thus returning the data implicitly (ES6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly braces are used to delimit the function body, therefore you need a `return` statement for return a value:

```
tasks.map((task) => {
  return <h3>{task.text}</h3>
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need **return** keyword in case you use curly braces in your arrow function.

```
tasks.map((task) => {
                       return <h3>{task.text}</h3>
                    }
)
```